# Can not find symbol in MainActivity.java React-native Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am adding image upload in my react native application. I installed well via npm and also linked them very well

```
react-native link react-native-image-picker
react-native link react-native-image-resizer
react-native link react-native-fs
```

now everytime i try to run the project i get these Errors

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   C:\projects\aurity\potatoo\potato\android\app\src\main\java\com\potato2\MainApplication.java:6:
>   error: package com.rnfs does not exist import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage;
>                  ^ C:\projects\aurity\potatoo\potato\android\app\src\main\java\com\potato2\MainApplication.java:7:
>   error: package fr.bamlab.rnimageresizer does not exist import
>   fr.bamlab.rnimageresizer.ImageResizerPackage;
>                                  ^ C:\projects\aurity\potatoo\potato\android\app\src\main\java\com\potato2\MainApplication.java:8:
>   error: package com.imagepicker does not exist import
>   com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
>                         ^ C:\projects\aurity\potatoo\potato\android\app\src\main\java\com\potato2\MainApplication.java:30:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               new RNFSPackage(),
>                   ^   symbol: class RNFSPackage C:\projects\aurity\potatoo\potato\android\app\src\main\java\com\potato2\MainApplication.java:31:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               new ImageResizerPackage(),
>                   ^   symbol: class ImageResizerPackage C:\projects\aurity\potatoo\potato\android\app\src\main\java\com\potato2\MainApplication.java:32:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               new ImagePickerPackage(),
>                   ^
>
> symbol: class ImagePickerPackage

When i check `MainApplication.java` and `MainActivity.java`  I have the package lines there.
Any one Help? I cant figure out why this is happening and the solution

Answer (score 2):

Adding following lines to the app/build.gradle fixed my issue,

```
dependencies {
compile project(path: ':react-native-image-resizer')
compile project(path: ':react-native-fs')
compile project(path: ':react-native-image-picker')
}
```